# How to deploy stack with docker-java client?

Tags: java, docker, stack

How to deploy stack with docker-java client?

ex)
docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stackdemo

Is there any function to run this command in java client?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to execute multiple commands I suggest you to write a shell script file and execute it from the java code.

```
{
   Process proc = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("./your_script.sh");                        
   proc.waitFor();
}
```

Another option if you want to only run 1 command you can use [ProcessBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html)

```
{
    String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash", "-c", "your_command", "with", "args"};
    Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
}
```

Comment: I guess there is no separate m,ethod in docker java client like createServiceCmd to deploy stack. Thank you for the answer!